# How to fix invisible image cropping in Vegas Pro

Tags: vegas-pro

Can anyone help me out, I don't even know how to search this on google, I just do small editing from time to time...

[image]

The red lines where put by me on the screenshot.

The image (is the text) is cropping when it reaches some "virtual line", both on top and bottom, how can I correct that to crop only on the black bars?

I'm using Sony Vegas Pro 15

Thank you all

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to fix this is to right-click on the pan/crop area and select Match Output Aspect.